# Consumer/producer problem: pause production on slow consumption

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I have a *producer* that reads blocks of text from the disk. Multiple *consumers* are doing computations on that blocks.

I would like producer to pause reading data from the disk if there are more that *n* blocks currently being computed over.

Have put it in pseudocode to illustrate what I would like to achieve.

```
// "produceBlocks" reads blocks from disk one by one
// and feeds them to lambda
produceBlocks(block -> {
  // (!) if activeCounter exceeds a THRESHOLD, then pause

  executorService.submit(() -> { 
     activeCounter.incrementAndGet();

     // do some work

     activeCounter.decrementAndGet();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I would like producer to pause reading data from the disk if there are more that n blocks currently being computed over."
The real task descrition is slightly different: *the producer, before reading data from the disk, should aquire a permit to do so*.
If your producer is a thread, then natural facility to manage permits is [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). Initialy it contains n permits. The producer, to read a block, aguires 1 permit with `Semaphore::aquire`. When the block is processed by the consumer, consumer releases 1 permit with `Semaphore::release`.

Another approach is to combine blocks and permits. Similary to the output queue from producer to consumer, create an input blocking queue for blocks. Initualy put there n blocks.  The producer, to read a block, first takes the next block from that queue. Consumer, after handling a block, returns it to the input queue.

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for. So much thanks, it will make my pipelines more robust and easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a fixed length queue for your thread pool and implement a RejectedExecuptionHandler to either run in the current thread or to pause and retry.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html#rejectedExecution(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor)

e.g.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html

This last option I have used effectively and it doesn't require extra code once the ExecutorService is configured.